# Yaml structure for PHP GAE

Tags: php, google-app-engine, yaml

I am new in developing with GAE and I am facing a problem when I deploy the app in cloud.

**> Error: Not Found The requested URL / was not found on this server.**

My app.yaml file is

```
application: xxxx
version: 3
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

env_variables:
  # Replace project, instance, database, user and password with the values obtained
  # when configuring your Cloud SQL instance.
  MYSQL_DSN: mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/xxxxx
  MYSQL_USER: xxx
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'xxxx'

handlers:

- url: /admin/js
  static_dir: admin/js

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: /fonts/(.*\.otf)
  static_dir: fonts/\1
  mime_type: application/x-font-otf

- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /admin/css
  static_dir: admin/css

- url: /admin/font-awesome
  static_dir: admin/font-awesome/\1
  mime_type: application/x-font-otf

- url: /admin/fonts
  static_dir: admin/fonts
  mime_type: application/x-font-otf

- url: /admin/images
  static_dir: admin/images

- url: /includes/js
  static_dir: /includes/js

- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1

- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

**The structure of my files is and this is what i am trying to succeed**

[image: image with structure]

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17620667/how-to-construct-a-app-yaml-file) topic.

**my Index.php code**

```
<?php require_once("admin/includes/Db_object.php") ?>
<?php require_once("admin/includes/init.php")?>
<?php include("includes/header.php"); ?>

<?php $photos = Photo::find_all();?>

<div class="row">

   <!-- Blog Entries Column -->
   <div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="thumbnails row">
       <?php  foreach ($photos as $photo): ?>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <a class = "thumbnail" href="#" data-toggle="lightbox" >
            <img class="img-responsive home_page_photo" src="admin/<?php echo $photo->picture_path();?>" alt="" ></a>
            </div>
            <?php endforeach;?>
         </div>
       </div>
<!-- /.row -->
<?php include("includes/footer.php"); ?>
```

EDIT: this is an error from my log file when i deploy it

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/MyGallery/admin/includes/new_config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /base/data/home/apps/s~my-project-test-150523/1.397682853077463759/admin/includes/init.php on line 10
18:30:31.878
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/MyGallery/admin/includes/new_config.php' (include_path='.;/base/data/home/apps/s~my-project-test-150523/1.397682853077463759/;/base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk') in /base/data/home/apps/s~my-project-test-150523/1.397682853077463759/admin/includes/init.php on line 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the leading `/` in the following `script` file paths:

```
- url: /footer.php
  script: /includes/footer.php

- url: /header.php
  script: /includes/header.php

- url: /navigation.php
  script: /includes/navigation.php

- url: /sidebar.php
  script: /includes/sidebar.php
```

Also check for other typos, like this one:

```
- url: /admin/edit_photo.php
  script: admin/dit_photo.php
```

Wouldn't it be easier to just use a generic `.php` script handler? Like the one shown in the documentation [Example](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appref#example):

```
# Serve php scripts.
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1
```

Side note: why do you even bother trying to translate/shorten some of the script paths (and greatly risking errors due to polluting the `app.yaml` file content in the process) when you're not actually using the shorter versions, for example in your `index.php`:

```
<?php require_once("admin/includes/Db_object.php") ?>
<?php require_once("admin/includes/init.php")?>
<?php include("includes/header.php"); ?>
```

If you drop the translation/shortening of the path then the above generic handler would cover them as well. Much cleaner (and safer).

**Update:**

The cleaner `app.yaml` allowed spotting some other possible problems (I'm not sure if they actually do cause trouble or not).

It seems you have attempts to use regular expression groupings with `static_dir` configs, for example:

```
- url: /fonts/(.*\.otf)
  static_dir: fonts/\1
  mime_type: application/x-font-otf
```

According to the respective rows in the [Handlers element](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appref#handlers_element) table, only `static_files` configs can use such groupings. Maybe you switched between the 2 configs and forgot to remove the groupings?

Also in one case you have a reference to a grouping (`\1`) in but no grouping definition in the corresponding `url` config:

```
- url: /admin/font-awesome
  static_dir: admin/font-awesome/\1
  mime_type: application/x-font-otf
```

Comment: i changed the handlers as you told me and locally works perfectly! (see my new app.yaml above). When i deploy it although i have the same error as i descriped....thanks for your respone!

Comment: Check the app's request logs in the developer console (https://console.cloud.google.com/logs), look for requests causing 404 errors - some other element referenced in your `index.php` may be missing. Other errors may also be relevant.

Comment: i saw my log file and it is messed up! i edit my question with something new if you want to take a look

Comment: From here on it's plain debugging your app code. I can't help much - I'm using python myself, not php. You may have some local paths somehow leaked into your app code as `C:/Users/xxx...` makes no sense on GAE.

Comment: finally after a lot of debugging the problem was the path and the some issues with the database...Still working although to deploy it on google app engine!!:)

Answer (score 0):

Change the last handler to:

```
- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

That sends any request not found in the handlers above to `index.php`.  Or, for more control:

```
- url: /
  script: index.php

- url: /.*
  script: not_found.php
```

Comment: i just tried it and nothing happened :(...thank you for your response

Comment: i posted my index.php. :)

Comment: Are you sure this is deploying, and you are going to proper URL?

Comment: locally i think it is working but when i deploy it i have the issue i described. In a desperate need to fix it i changed my app.yaml file so if you want take a look again. is there any clear tutorial for handlers except google's?

Comment: finally after a lot of debugging the problem was the path and the some issues with the database...Still working although to deploy it on google app engine!!:)